# ExactOnline: Token is not allowed, because of invalid or empty chainId

Tags: oauth-2.0, exact-online

We have a java application that connects to ExactOnline for performing the operations.
The connection works fine for almost 9days and then it will start complaining about the below exception:

"Request from start.exactonline.nl returned an error (response code: 400, response: { "error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Token is not allowed, because of invalid or empty chainId"

After encountering this error we have to force re-authorize the application by the user to get the new accessToken.

Now I am getting the below error as well:

"Request to token endpoint [https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token"](https://start.exactonline.nl/api/oauth2/token%22)
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error message it's background and the solutions are explained at https://forums.invantive.com/t/exact-online-error-token-is-not-allowed-because-of-invalid-or-empty-chainid-on-exact-online/2226

Comment: Thank you for providing the response, I have seen this blog post. But it is referring to the forums.invantive.com is it exact online forum itself?

Comment: No, it is from our company which links to over 15.000 Exact companies and had major issues in keeping production up last year due to this issue and several others. The post and related posts describe the issue and the design choices Exact made and implemented in deviation from industry standards.